# Border not reaching edges

Tags: html, css

i'm making a responsive website but the border between the first and second title has a gap in mobile view (700px). What should I do to remove the gap?

Example code: https://codepen.io/Link0w0/pen/ZEyBqWE

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    main{
        float: none;
        border-right: none;
        width: 90%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    aside{
        float: none;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .wrapper{
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you specify which gap you mean?

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/1O0aQ1u.png](https://i.imgur.com/1O0aQ1u.png)

Comment: you mean the line between the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the `main` has `margin` on the right side while the `aside` has `margin` on the left side. try to remove it